# Swagger is rendering values of one enum instead of all other enums in project

Tags: swagger

In my REST application there are a lot of post end points that are having enums inside https requests.
When I open swagger UI and check sample request for any of these post methods enum value is everywhere first value in one particular enum. So if I have enum called Fruits

```
public enum Fruits {
    APPLE,
    ORANGE
}
```

and another one

```
public enum Vegetables {
    TOMATO,
    POTATO
}
```

I am not able to see e.g. value "TOMATO" anywhere in http sample requests in swagger where Vegetables enum is used. Everywhere there is always "APPLE".

I'm editing question and giving exact example.
Here is one post method:

```
@PostMapping(path = "search")
public Result<Page<CountryCodeRecord>> searchCountryCodes(
        @RequestBody PageableSearchRequest<CountryCodeQuery,CountryCodeOrder> pageableSearchRequest) {
    return new Result<>(countryCodeFacade.search(pageableSearchRequest));
}
```

These are used classes:

```
public class PageableSearchRequest<T extends Query, S extends QueryOrder> implements Serializable {    
    private T query;   
    private SearchSort<S> searchSort;   
    private PageSelection pageSelection;  
    ...
}

public class CountryCodeQuery implements Query, Serializable {
    private String name;
    private Boolean active;

    //...
}

public enum CountryCodeOrder implements QueryOrder {    
    NAME("name"),
    ACTIVE("active");   
}
```

And this is swagger sample request:

```
{
  "pageSelection": {
    "pageNumber": 0,
    "pageSize": 0
  },
  "query": {
    "active": true,    
    "name": "string"    
  },
  "searchSort": {
    "orders": [
      {
        "orderBy": "**PA_NUMBER**",
        "sortDirection": "ASC"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This line "orderBy": "**PA_NUMBER**" should be "orderBy": "**NAME**".

Comment: Show us some code please. Your controller, your request model ...

Comment: I added it in question. Thanks for helping.